# SQL_Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your precious help :-)

Imagine the ZAP_TEST_AP table composed of columns A1, B1 and C1 which contains the info shown in the image below

[image]

| row number | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | 11111 | host1 |
| 2 | PRIMARY | (null) | host1 |
| 3 | (null) | (null) | host1 |
| 4 | PRIMARY | 22222 | host2 |
| 5 | (null) | 22222 | host2 |
| 6 | (null) | (null) | host2 |
| 7 | PRIMARY | (null) | host3 |
| 8 | (null) | (null) | host3 |
| 9 | (null) | 44444 | host4 |
| 10 | (null) | (null) | host4 |
| 11 | (null) | (null) | host5 |

my goal is to make a query that is able to extract only the rows 1,4,7,9:

| row number | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | 11111 | host1 |
| 4 | PRIMARY | 22222 | host2 |
| 7 | PRIMARY | (null) | host3 |
| 9 | (null) | 44444 | host4 |

that is to say:

1. in the case in which (rows 1,2,3) for the same host1 (field c1) I have three rows where for one there are both a1 and b1, one both null and one where only a1 is set, I would like to extract only the one where both are present --> row 1
2. in the case in which (rows 4,5,6) for the same host2 (field c1) I have three rows where for one there are both a1 and b1, one both null and one where only b1 is set, I would like to extract only the one where both are present --> row 4
3. in the case in which (rows 7,8) for the same host3 (field c1) I have two rows where for one they are both null and one where only a1 is set, I would like to extract only the one where a1 is set --> row 7
4. in the case in which (rows 9,10) for the same host4 (field c1) I have two rows where for one they are both null and one where only b1 is set, I would like to extract only the one where b1 is set --> row 9
5. in case (row 11) for host5 (field c1) I have only one row and both a1 and b1 are null, I would like it not to be extracted

I hope I have clearly explained my problem :-(

Thanks in advance for your cooperation !!!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: What if for the same host you have two distinct rows, both of which have non-`null` values in all columns? Which row do you want to pick then? Similarly, if for another host the `a1` value is always `null`, the `b1` value is always non-`null`, but there are several rows (for the same host, all with `a1` being `null`), with distinct, non-`null` values for `b1`? Which particular row from those rows do you want to pick?

Comment: What if, for a particular host, there are two rows: in one, `a1` is non-`null` and `b1` is `null`, and in the other `a1` is `null` and `b1` is non-`null`? Which of these rows do you pick then?

Comment: thanks @mathguy for your questions. all lines that meet the conditions, then to answer your questions --> both (or more) rows in all three cases you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover the cases I mentioned in my comments to your question (cases when more than one row may be shown in the output, for the same host), we need to use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`. I would also write the `case` expression in a more user-friendly way, and filter out the rows where both `a1` and `b1` are `null` from the beginning; something like this:

```
select a1, b1, c1
from   (
         select a1, b1, c1,
                dense_rank() over ( partition by c1
                                    order by case when a1 is not null
                                                   and b1 is not null then 2
                                                                      else 1
                                                   end
                                             desc) as rnk
         from   zap_test_ap z
         where  a1 is not null or b1 is not null
       )
where  rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: thank you all for the help you have provided me

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `null` values and take the first one using `row_number()`:

```
select c1, c2, c3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c3
                                order by (case when c1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                                         (case when c2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: If for a given host, all rows have both `a1` and `b1` as `null`, the OP doesn't want anything for that host in the output. See `host5` in his sample data and output. I don't see where you are handling that in your query. (Note also the further clarification in comments under his question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this solution using decode function in the order by clause of row_number analytic function.

```sql
select row_number, A1, B1, C1
from (
  select row_number, A1, B1, C1
    , row_number()over(partition by C1 order by decode(A1, null, 0, 1) + decode(B1, null, 0, 1) desc, row_number ) rnb
    , max(decode(A1, null, 0, 1) + decode(B1, null, 0, 1))over(partition by C1)max_presence
  from ZAP_TEST_AP
)
where rnb = 1
and max_presence > 0
;
```

Comment: If for a given host, all rows have both `a1` and `b1` as `null`, the OP doesn't want anything for that host in the output. See `host5` in his sample data and output. I don't see where you are handling that in your query. (Note also the further clarification in comments under his question.)

Comment: Thansk @mathguy for pointing out this last condition. I hadn't got it before. Now, I made my answer to cover it.